# Pulseaudio don't start when booting (Kali)

Tags: boot, kali-linux, audio, pulseaudio

I need to enter the "pulseaudio" command after each boot to get the sound back.

(Before doing it, my sound card don't appear in settings, sound keys don't work, no sound logo and no sound of course)

**Do you have an idea to make it start at boot ?**

By the way the mic bar/logo dissapear when I enter the command.

Comment: You're running Kali, which deliberately and intentionally starts no services at boot.

If you want things like `pulsesudio` don't run Kali.

Comment: I just would like sound after boot, this command is the only way I found to get audio working. I don't know pulseaudio and I'm not a pro with Linux, but I want to keep Kali.

Comment: Are you running in a VM?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `pulseaudio` then edit the config file as follows:

```
sudo gedit /etc/pulse/daemon.conf
```

to say:

> daemonize = yes

Note, there is no `;` in front. If there is still no sound on startup, the also try to run the following:

```
systemctl --user enable pulseaudio && systemctl --user start pulseaudio
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are running as root, Pulse-audio starts on boot with Kali but stops when you log in as root, there are security issues with running Pulseaudio as root, this is why it stops on root login. Yet annoying security is bad security, if you know the risks, here is a nice solution i implemented after reading this post- 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/141229/how-to-add-a-shell-script-to-launcher-as-shortcut

1- make a folder for bash script and icon(stick it where you want, call it anything).
2- pick a sexy icon, stick it in the folder
3- open a editor and paste-

"#!/bin/bash

pulseaudio -D"

4-save, make it executable by typing "chmod +x name-of-your-script"

5-type "cd /usr/share/applications"

6-type "nano name-whateve.desktop"

7-paste in-

[Desktop Entry]

Type=Application

Terminal=true

Name=anyname

Icon=/path/to/icon/youricon

Exec=/path/to/file/yourfile

8- edit paths, name, save

9 open tweak tool>startup applications, find your icon, add it :)